# How to close thread winapi

Tags: multithreading, winapi

what is the rigth way to close Thread in Winapi, threads don't use common resources. 
I am creating threads with CreateThread , but I don't know how to close it correctly in   ,because someone suggest to use TerminateThread , others ExitThread , but what is the correct way to close it .
Also where should I call closing function in  WM_CLOSE or WM_DESTROY ? 
 Thx in advance .

Comment: First questions - are you shutting down your app and, if so, do you need to 'close' the thread in question?  Does if hold data that must be flushed to disk, or DB connections that must not be held open, or the like?

Answer (score 2):

The "nicest" way to close a thread in Windows is by "telling" the thread to shutdown via some thread-safe signaling mechanism, then simply letting it reach its demise its own, potentially waiting for it to do so via one of the WaitForXXXX functions if completion detection is needed (which is frequently the case). Something like:

Main thread:

```
// some global event all threads can reach
ghStopEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

// create the child thread
hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadProc, NULL, 0, NULL);

//
// ... continue other work.
//

// tell thread to stop
SetEvent(ghStopEvent);

// now wait for thread to signal termination
WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);

// important. close handles when no longer needed
CloseHandle(hThread);
CloseHandle(ghStopEvent);
```

Child thread:

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID pv)
{
    // do threaded work
    while (WaitForSingleObject(ghStopEvent, 1) == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
    {
         // do thread busy work
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Obviously things can get a lot more complicated once you start putting it in practice. If by "common" resources you mean something like the `ghStopEvent` in the prior example, it becomes considerably more difficult. Terminating a child thread via `TerminateThread` is **strongly** discouraged because there is no logical cleanup performed *at all*. The warnings specified in the [`TerminateThread documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are self-explanatory, and should be heeded. With great power comes....

Finally, even the *called* thread invoking `ExitThread` is *not* required explicitly *by you*, and though you can do so, I strongly advise **against** it in C++ programs. It is called *for you* once the thread procedure logically returns from the `ThreadProc`. I prefer the model above simply because it is dead-easy to implement and supports full RAII of C++ object cleanup, which *neither* `ExitThread` nor `TerminateThread` provide. For example, the `ExitThread` documentation :

> ...in C++ code, the thread is exited before any destructors can be called
>   or any other automatic cleanup can be performed. Therefore, in C++
>   code, **you should return from your thread function**.

Anyway, start simple. Get a handle on things with super-simple examples, then work your way up from there. There are a *ton* of multi-threaded examples on the web, Learn from the good ones and challenge yourself to identify the bad ones.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to figure out what sort of behaviour you need to have.

Following is a simple description of the methods taken from documentation:

"TerminateThread is a dangerous function that should only be used in the most extreme cases. You should call TerminateThread only if you know exactly what the target thread is doing, and you control all of the code that the target thread could possibly be running at the time of the termination. For example, TerminateThread can result in the following problems:
If the target thread owns a critical section, the critical section will not be released.
If the target thread is allocating memory from the heap, the heap lock will not be released.
If the target thread is executing certain kernel32 calls when it is terminated, the kernel32 state for the thread's process could be inconsistent.
If the target thread is manipulating the global state of a shared DLL, the state of the DLL could be destroyed, affecting other users of the DLL."

So if you need your thread to terminate at any cost, call this method.

About ExitThread, this is more graceful. By calling ExitThread, you're telling to windows you're done with that calling thread, so the rest of the code isn't going to get called. It's a bit like calling exit(0).

"ExitThread is the preferred method of exiting a thread. When this function is called (either explicitly or by returning from a thread procedure), the current thread's stack is deallocated, all pending I/O initiated by the thread is canceled, and the thread terminates. If the thread is the last thread in the process when this function is called, the thread's process is also terminated."